# The life cycle among the Browser, Apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I realized that, when the client enters the address in their browser, the HTTP Request massage is sent to the web server by the browser. The web server receives the HTTP Request, read it and finds the requested file, finally.

When the suffix of the requested file is `.php`, the web server opens it on the RAM and then refers it to the PHP Interpreter. The file is read by the PHP Interpreter line by line, and those lines which are out of the `<?php ?>` block, are ignored as the output by the interpreter`(?)`, and those that are in the PHP block are interpreted line by line. If I am right here, so I continue the debate by citing some examples.

We suppose that `index.php` has following codes:

```
Example Html Code
<php
    echo 'this is a test.';
    // another php codes
?>
```

The PHP Interpreter doesn’t compile the first line, because it is not in the PHP block, but, since there is an Html tag so the PHP Interpreter considers the adaptable header automatically and puts the first in the output, however, insomuch that the file interpretation is not complete, so the header and the output have not been sent to the web server, yet. Is it right?

Then, the next line is compiled by the interpreter.
the next line locates in the PHP block, so it is compiled by the interpreter and it puts the text that should be `echo` in the continuance of the previous output. Consequently, other codes are interpreted similarly and when the `index.php` file is compiled completely, the interpreter sends the header and outputs into the web server.
they are send in the form of an HTTP Response to the web browser by the web server, as well.

**Is this conclusion true for the cycle among the browser, web server and the PHP Interpreter?**

How much request and response is formed between the browser and the web server?
And how much request and response is formed between the web server and the PHP Interpreter?

Is the file opened on the RAM by the web server or the PHP Interpreter?

**When the interpreter considers the header, is it sent to the web server immediately or is the whole interpretation of the page sent when it was completed?**

**When the PHP Interpreter meet the first Html tag or some commands such as `echo` and such like, does it send the output immediately or does it send all outputs outright with the header after the page is interpreted completely?**

Comment: Like all HTTP requests, the response is interpreted completely before being sent to the browser. Several HTTP requests may make up on page (for instance, you may retrieve multiple images, CSS files, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: You appear to think of PHP as a simple language that gets parsed and interpreted line by line. That's only true in really ancient languages like Basic or Windows Batch.

Comment: Is the file opened on the RAM by the web server or the PHP Interpreter?